# How to set up IntelliJ Idea to highlight library types in Scala code?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, syntax-highlighting

I've managed to set up IntelliJ Idea to highlight most of the types, including my own classes and basic types like Int, but library classes (like Node (scala.xml.Node) and even String) are not highlighted anyway. How to fix this?

PS: Links to good-quality up-to-date fully Scala-aware colouring themes for Idea are welcome in comments. All I've seen are quite mediocre.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to distinguish by color your own types from library types?

Comment: @ziggystar No, I don't want (but I wouldn't mind). I just want all the types to be highlighted. I want `Int`, `String` and `MyClass` and `Unit` to be always highlighted (a same way is ok, but I want to distinguish them from variables names and other code) wherever they are met (after `:` usually).

Comment: Have you tried customizing the syntax highlighting for Scala? I think all you need is there.

Comment: Yes, as I've specified: I've managed to set up IntelliJ Idea to highlight most of the types, including my own classes and basic types, but not library types.

Answer (score 0):

So what's NOT bold+italic on the following image that you want to have marked?

[image: my syntax highlighting proposal]

Comment: Can't find any example here. As I've said, examples are String and Node (scala.xml.Node).

Comment: Just write `def myF(s: String){...}` and try to get String highlighted.

Comment: @Ivan I checked and `String` is also bold under these settings.

Comment: @Ivan and you can get `String` with `Scala type alias` in the settings.

Comment: `Scala type alias` solved the problem applying to `String` and `JValue`, but not for `Node`.